# I want to make insertig sorting visualizer,the sorting works but not the visualizer

Tags: python, pygame, insertion-sort

Like the title says I wanted to create a visualized Insertion sort with python and pygame. The sort works perfectly but when it comes to visualize it it never gets the correct output.

The sort works perfectly,but the screen bars donot change their position. I also added some colours to better understand the code..

The Code:-

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("SORTING VISUALS")


class Rect:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.colour = BLACK

    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, (self.X, self.Y, self.width, self.height))

    def changeCol(self, colour):
        self.colour = colour


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
GRAY = (148, 0, 211)

L = []
rect = []
n = 100  # n belongs till [50,220]
WidthOfEachBar = 800 // (n + 1)


def array(n_):
    global L
    arr = [(3 * i) for i in range(1, n_ + 1)]
    for a in range(n_):
        random_no = random.choice(arr)
        L.append(random_no + 10)
        arr.remove(random_no)


array(n)

for i in range(n):
    x = (i + 1) * (1 + WidthOfEachBar)
    y = 680 - L[i]
    rect.append(Rect(x, y, WidthOfEachBar, L[i]))


# /*-------------------------------------- INSERTION SORT FUNCTION----------------------------------------------------*/
def equal(b):
    a = Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
    a.X = b.X
    a.Y = b.Y
    a.width = b.width
    a.height = b.height
    a.colour = b.colour
    return a


def insertionsort():
    global rect, n
    for oo in range(n):
        print(rect[oo].height, end=" ")
    print()
    for i in range(1, n):
        print("outer loop")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        rect[i].colour = GREEN
        key = rect[i]
        key.X = rect[i].X
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and key.height < rect[j].height:
            for oo in range(n):
                print(rect[oo].height, end=" ")
            print()
            rect[j + 1] = rect[j]
            rect[j + 1].X = rect[j].X
            j = j - 1

        rect[j + 1] = key
        rect[j + 1].X = key.X

        screen.fill(WHITE)
        for a in range(n):
            rect[a].show()
        pygame.display.update()
        rect[j+1].colour = BLACK


sorted_insertion = False
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
    if not sorted_insertion:
        insertionsort()
        for oo in range(n):
            print(rect[oo].height, end=" ")
        print()
        print("came once")
        sorted_insertion = True
        for a in range(n):
            rect[a].show()
        pygame.display.update()
```

Here the screen is updated everytime, but I couldn't understand the problem. The code is much fishy,I know but any help would be great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to swap the list elements and the `.X` attribute, rather then assign if:

<s>`rect[j + 1] = rect[j]`</s>
<s>`rect[j + 1].X = rect[j].X`</s>

```py
rect[j + 1], rect[j] = rect[j], rect[j + 1]
rect[j + 1].X, rect[j].X = rect[j].X, rect[j + 1].X
```

Function `insertionsort`:

```py
def insertionsort():
    global rect, n
    for oo in range(n):
        print(rect[oo].height, end=" ")
    print()
    for i in range(1, n):
        print("outer loop")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        rect[i].colour = GREEN
        key = rect[i]
        key.X = rect[i].X
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and key.height < rect[j].height:
            for oo in range(n):
                print(rect[oo].height, end=" ")
            print()
            rect[j + 1], rect[j] = rect[j], rect[j + 1]
            rect[j + 1].X, rect[j].X = rect[j].X, rect[j + 1].X
            j = j - 1

        rect[j + 1], key = key, rect[j + 1]
        rect[j + 1].X, key.X = key.X, rect[j + 1].X

        screen.fill(WHITE)
        for a in range(n):
            rect[a].show()
        pygame.display.update()
        rect[j+1].colour = BLACK
```

[image]